# How to smooth scroll to an anchor if a user hasn't scrolled in 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, delay, scrollto, anchor-scroll

So basically, thanks to a solution I have found already on stackoverflow, I have gotten as far as creating a smooth scroll to an anchor after 5 seconds.

The bit that I can't seem to add to this is simply having this ONLY trigger if a user hasn't already scrolled within the 5 seconds as this can be an irritating experience.

I have experimented with trying to add .scrollTo() in various different ways and wrapping to whole thing in another function but apart from basic understanding and tweaking of Javascript I don't really have much knowledge.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/

var zxcScrollTo={

 Scroll:function(o){
  var a=document.getElementById(o.AnchorID),ms=o.Animate,s=!document.body.scrollTop?[document.documentElement.scrollLeft,document.documentElement.scrollTop]:[document.body.scrollLeft,document.body.scrollTop];
  if (a){
   this.animate(this,s,this.pos(a),new Date(),typeof(ms)=='number'&&ms>0?ms:1000);
  }
 },

 animate:function(o,f,t,srt,mS){
  clearTimeout(o.to);
  var ms=new Date()-srt,x=(t[0]-f[0])/mS*ms+f[0],y=(t[1]-f[1])/mS*ms+f[1];
  if (isFinite(x)&&isFinite(y)){
   window.scrollTo(x,y);
  }
  if (ms<mS){
   o.to=setTimeout(function(){ o.animate(o,f,t,srt,mS); },10);
  }
  else {
   window.scrollTo(t[0],t[1]);
  }
 },

 pos:function(obj){
  var rtn=[0,0];
  while(obj){
   rtn[0]+=obj.offsetLeft;
   rtn[1]+=obj.offsetTop;
   obj=obj.offsetParent;
  }
  return rtn;
 }


}
setTimeout(function(){
  zxcScrollTo.Scroll({
   AnchorID:'anchor',
   Animate:2000
  });
 },5000);

/*]]>*/
</script>
```

**ANSWER:**

Many thanks to @ByteHamster.

This code will smooth scroll user to an ID tag after 5000ms but not trigger if user has already started scrolling:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var zxcScrollTo={

 Scroll:function(o){
  var a=document.getElementById(o.AnchorID),ms=o.Animate,s=!document.body.scrollTop?[document.documentElement.scrollLeft,document.documentElement.scrollTop]:[document.body.scrollLeft,document.body.scrollTop];
  if (a){
   this.animate(this,s,this.pos(a),new Date(),typeof(ms)=='number'&&ms>0?ms:1000);
  }
 },

 animate:function(o,f,t,srt,mS){
  clearTimeout(o.to);
  var ms=new Date()-srt,x=(t[0]-f[0])/mS*ms+f[0],y=(t[1]-f[1])/mS*ms+f[1];
  if (isFinite(x)&&isFinite(y)){
   window.scrollTo(x,y);
  }
  if (ms<mS){
   o.to=setTimeout(function(){ o.animate(o,f,t,srt,mS); },10);
  }
  else {
   window.scrollTo(t[0],t[1]);
  }
 },

 pos:function(obj){
  var rtn=[0,0];
  while(obj){
   rtn[0]+=obj.offsetLeft;
   rtn[1]+=obj.offsetTop;
   obj=obj.offsetParent;
  }
  return rtn;
 }


}

var wasScrolled = false;

window.onscroll = function () {
   wasScrolled = true;

}

function doSmoothScrollToAnchor() {
    if (wasScrolled === false) {
        zxcScrollTo.Scroll({
            AnchorID: 'anchor',
            Animate: 2000
        });
    }
}

setTimeout(doSmoothScrollToAnchor, 5000);


</script>
```

Comment: why do you need to do that?? just say if the user has not scrolled but is reading something on the screen? its irritating if the page scrolls on its own

Comment: @RRR, the page has been constructed to be visually aesthetic above the fold with the main content below the fold. Against the norm, this works well. The scroll after a delay is simply to transition users to the content after about 5 seconds which is all the time needed really to take in what is above the fold after the page is loaded. If a user has already scrolled down or has started to I don't want the autoscroll to trigger.

Comment: in that case after 5 seconds  you should  check whether the  `scrollTop <= the element.height`  if true scroll else do nothing as user has already scrolled

Comment: Thanks @RRR, it is exactly what I am trying to do but I am struggling with how to fit it in.

Comment: kindly check the following fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/n96rb7pp/ ... sorry couldnt use your example but i have created it on similar lines... just wait for 3 secs and the page scrolls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Set a variable that gets changed as soon as the user scrolls:
var wasScrolled = false;
window.onscroll = function () {
  wasScrolled = true;
}

// Before actually scrolling via Javascript, check if the page was scrolled manually:
function doSmoothScrollToAnchor() {
    if(wasScrolled === false) {
        alert("Was not scrolled");
    } else {
        alert("The user scrolled manually");
    }
}
setTimeout(doSmoothScrollToAnchor, 3000);
```

```html
Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />
Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />
Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />
Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Ironically, although it sounds wrong, I do want to force the scroll if a user hasn't initiated scrolling because there isn't much to read above the fold. It consists of a logo and short slider. I apologise, I should have explained this better. Is there any way to tweak your solution to do almost the opposite? In other words only scroll if a user has not yet started scrolling?

Comment: Additionally I am looking for it to be a one time thing once the page has loaded after which the user can scroll freely without any further forced direction.

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood your question. Have a look at my updated answer ;)

Comment: This looks to be the perfect solution logically. For some reason it wasn't working and by testing a few things I narrowed it down to the fact that 'wasScrolled' is always getting set to 'true' even though I wasn't scrolling on loading. Tested in a few browsers and even devices to make sure but for me the occurrence repeats. Setting: if(wasScrolled === true) triggers the function with no (manual) scrolling. Could a plugin or previous code be setting the scroll value to > 0 already? Thanks for your answers so far. I'm sure for most people this would already work.

Comment: You can try to set `wasScrolled` to `false` with a timeout of 200ms :D

Comment: I have been looking at this for hours now trying to work it out and I simply can't so I will have to call it a day. I know this is the correct answer for what I asked so I will mark it as correct. But for me, no matter what I change wasScrolled is always getting set to true with no interaction at all. If there are any alternatives to detect scrolling or you know of any reason why the browser thinks the user has already scrolled with no movement then I would appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: Tried delaying with setTimeout function for 200ms and 2000ms with no result. wasScrolled still set to true unless I entirely remove the window.onscroll function which of course defeats the object. It most likely looks like something is wrong on my side because the code looks good. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try something like this? `setTimeout(function(){window.onscroll=...},200);`

Comment: Hmm if I create a snippet here on Stack Overflow, it works. It must be something different on your page,

Comment: Yep just tested that version of code on my page and sure enough the "The user scrolled manually" message is triggered without any scrolling. It's a great answer and it will work once I've identified what on earth is causing that on my page. I will post the entire code snippet with your mods as an answer incase it helps anyone else. Thanks for your help on this. I searched for weeks for what I thought was going to be a simple bit of code and I could only get as far as what I first posted.

Comment: It's enough to tick the answer that solved your problem, you don't need to copy the answer to the question. That's how Stack Overflow works ;) By the way, welcome to this great website!

Answer (score 0):

Try the `clearTimeout()` function. It clears the timer and sets it again so that it starts all over again :)

```js
var timer = setTimeout(doSmoothScrollToAnchor, 5000);
var scrolled = false;
var zxcScrollTo={

 Scroll:function(o){
  var a=document.getElementById(o.AnchorID),ms=o.Animate,s=!document.body.scrollTop?[document.documentElement.scrollLeft,document.documentElement.scrollTop]:[document.body.scrollLeft,document.body.scrollTop];
  if (a){
   this.animate(this,s,this.pos(a),new Date(),typeof(ms)=='number'&&ms>0?ms:1000);
  }
 },

 animate:function(o,f,t,srt,mS){
  clearTimeout(o.to);
  var ms=new Date()-srt,x=(t[0]-f[0])/mS*ms+f[0],y=(t[1]-f[1])/mS*ms+f[1];
  if (isFinite(x)&&isFinite(y)){
   window.scrollTo(x,y);
  }
  if (ms<mS){
   o.to=setTimeout(function(){ o.animate(o,f,t,srt,mS); },10);
  }
  else {
   window.scrollTo(t[0],t[1]);
  }
 },

 pos:function(obj){
  var rtn=[0,0];
  while(obj){
   rtn[0]+=obj.offsetLeft;
   rtn[1]+=obj.offsetTop;
   obj=obj.offsetParent;
  }
  return rtn;
 }


}
function doSmoothScrollToAnchor() {
        zxcScrollTo.Scroll({
            AnchorID: 'anchor',
            Animate: 2000
        });
        scrolled = true;
}
window.onscroll = function(e){
  if(!scrolled){
 clearInterval(timer);
  }
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 650px;
  background-color: #444;
}
#anchor{
  width: 100%;
  height: 650px;
  background-color: red;
}
#div3{
  width: 100%;
  height: 650px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#div4{
  width: 100%;
  height: 650px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
</div>
<div id="anchor">
</div>
<div id="div3">
</div>
<div id="div4">
</div>
```

Hope it helped :)

**EDIT** I read you wanted it to be a one time event, so I altered my code

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Essentially it fulfils the function of delaying the scroll if a user already scrolls within the 5 seconds. However it will then scroll at the point where a user stops for any period of time thats longer than 5 seconds after that. This ultimately what I am trying to avoid. So if a user scrolls once within the 1st 5 seconds (or 'x' seconds) no function is triggered. Thanks again though, this would be very useful for anyone looking to trigger an action if a user is inactive for any fixed amount of time.

Comment: Ah I understand now, I see you already have a correct answer but I will update my code anyway :P